# Regex: Non-capture group

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

[Regex beginner] In Sublime Text 3, how do I find, say, `aa` such that there is no `a` on the immediate left and right, and replace it with `aaa`? I tried:

```
(?:[^a])(aa)(?:[^a])
```

but that selects four characters. How do I select the `aa` only?

Comment: Use `(?<!a)aa(?!a)`

Comment: Use negative lookbehind.

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks. Would you kindly state it as an answer so that the question looks answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of a negative [lookbehind and lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!a)aa(?!a)
```

The `(?<!a)` fails the match if there is a `a` immediately to the left of the current location and `(?!a)` fails the match if there is an `a` immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [PCRE regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aJIM11/2) (SublimeText3 uses PCRE engine).